# How to generate and validate a list of TextEditingController and upload the List of textEditingController to firebase -flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I created an upload page where user picks multiple images and then assign a price for each image.I'm want to achieve this with a list of TextEditing controllers and displaying textfield under each image.

First I created the list and later generate the list according to the length of the images.

```dart
List<TextEditingController> _controller;
   
Widget buildGridView() {
   return Container(
     height: 400,
     child: GridView.count(
       crossAxisCount: 1,
       scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
       children: List.generate(images.length, (index) {
         //I can't use the index I defined below in controller. 
         //says (i) is undefined so I used the index which defined above.
         //Am I doing it right?
         _controller = List.generate(images.length, (i) => TextEditingController());
         Asset asset = images[index];
         return Padding(
           padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
           child: Container(
             height: 100,
             width: 100,
             child: Column(
               children: [
                 ClipRRect(
                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
                    child: AssetThumb(
                     asset: asset,
                     width: 300,
                     height: 300,
                   ),
                 ),
                 Form(
                   key: _formKey,
                   child: TextFormField(
                     keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                     validator: (String value) {
                       double sal = double.tryParse(value);
                       if (sal == null) {
                         return 'enter or delete row';
                       }
                       return null;
                     },
                     controller: _controller[index],
                   ),
                 ),
               ],
             ),
          ),
         );
       }),
     ),
   );
 }
```

Here _formkey gives me error `duplicate key found`.Can I generate a list of formKeys according to the length of images?

at last I want to upload the list of textEditingControllers. I has `.toList()` parameter but not `.text`

Answer (score 0):

1. You should have just one `Form` widget with one `FormKey` and that should wrap the all the `TextFormField` widgets.

   > Form class
   >
   > An optional container for grouping together multiple form field
   > widgets (e.g. TextField widgets).
   >
   > https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Form-class.html

   So in this case, your `Form` should wrap the `GridView`.

   Here is your `buildGridView` method with the update:

   ```dart
   Widget buildGridView() {
     return Container(
       height: 400,
       child: Form(
         key: _formKey,
         child: GridView.count(
           crossAxisCount: 1,
           scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
           children: List.generate(images.length, (index) {
             //I can use the index I defined below in controller. 
             //says i is undefined so I used the index which defined above.
             //Am I doing it right?
             _controller =
                 List.generate(images.length, (i) => TextEditingController());
             Asset asset = images[index];
             return Padding(
               padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
               child: Container(
                 height: 100,
                 width: 100,
                 child: Column(
                   children: [
                     ClipRRect(
                       borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
                       child: AssetThumb(
                         asset: asset,
                         width: 300,
                         height: 300,
                       ),
                     ),
                     TextFormField(
                       keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                       validator: (String value) {
                         double sal = double.tryParse(value);
                         if (sal == null) {
                           return 'enter or delete row';
                         }
                         return null;
                       },
                       controller: _controller[index],
                     ),
                   ],
                 ),
               ),
             );
           }),
         ),
       ),
     );
   }
   ```
2. In order to get the list of text from the controller list, you need to map each controller to get the text.

   ```dart
    List<String> textList = _controller.map((x) => x.text).toList();
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your help so far but the `List<String> textList` extracts only the last string. The previous indexes are empty strings.Heres the log.`I/flutter ( 9270): [, , , , , 8966]`

Comment: it retrieves the length of the list correctly but sets the string to `""` except  for the last one

Comment: What did you expect the log to print instead of `[, , , , , 8966]`?

Comment: The other strings which were entered by the user. Like this`[459,634,7373,737,8966]`. Instead the list turns into this `[, , , , 8966]`. Why are the strings before the last string are being set to `""`?